# Stargazer dosen't show number of observations for robust s.e

Tags: r, regression, stargazer, robust

I'm trying to use stargazer to output some regression results with robust standard errors, but the lines in the bottom for values like nobs and f stat doesn't show. here are the code and the output.

```
r_FEB1_se <- coeftest(r_FEB1, vcov = vcovHC(r_FEB1, method = "arellano", type = "HC3", cluster = "group"))
r_FED1_se <- coeftest(r_FED1, vcov = vcovHC(r_FED1, method = "arellano", type = "HC3", cluster = "group"))
r_FEF1_se <- coeftest(r_FEF1, vcov = vcovHC(r_FEF1, method = "arellano", type = "HC3", cluster = "group"))
r_FEH1_se <- coeftest(r_FEH1, vcov = vcovHC(r_FEH1, method = "arellano", type = "HC3", cluster = "group"))

r_FEB2_se <- coeftest(r_FEB2, vcov = vcovHC(r_FEB2, method = "arellano", type = "HC3", cluster = "group"))
r_FED2_se <- coeftest(r_FED2, vcov = vcovHC(r_FED2, method = "arellano", type = "HC3", cluster = "group"))
r_FEF2_se <- coeftest(r_FEF2, vcov = vcovHC(r_FEF2, method = "arellano", type = "HC3", cluster = "group"))
r_FEH2_se <- coeftest(r_FEH2, vcov = vcovHC(r_FEH2, method = "arellano", type = "HC3", cluster = "group"))

stargazer::stargazer(r_FEB1_se,r_FEB2_se,r_FED1_se,r_FED2_se,r_FEF1_se,r_FEF2_se,r_FEH1_se,r_FEH2_se, type = "text")

=========================================================================================================================
                                                                          Dependent variable:                            
                                               --------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                                 (1)      (2)     (3)      (4)      (5)      (6)       (7)        (8)    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-1`                      0.594*  0.653*  1.193*** 1.368*** 0.973*** 1.031***  0.841***   0.904*** 
                                               (0.337)  (0.338) (0.450)  (0.458)  (0.295)  (0.306)   (0.294)    (0.299)  

`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-1`         0.000*           0.000             0.000            0.00000***           
                                               (0.000)          (0.000)           (0.000)            (0.000)             

`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-1` 0.010***         0.031***           -0.006            0.009**             
                                               (0.003)          (0.007)           (0.005)            (0.004)             

`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-2`                  0.000            0.000             0.000              0.00000***
                                                        (0.000)          (0.000)           (0.000)              (0.000)  

`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-2`          0.008**          0.025***          -0.011**              0.007   
                                                        (0.003)          (0.007)           (0.005)              (0.005)  

=========================================================================================================================
=========================================================================================================================
Note:                                                                                         *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: You may want to try [`texreg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/index.html) package as an alternative.

Comment: I have tried to use it but it shows the same result, the number of observations does not show, am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, you're using `"coeftest"` objects which don't include all the information that `"lm"` objects do. See my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `"lm"` objects are used to produce the tables. But you may override the values. Since I'm more familiar with the [`texreg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/index.html) package, I hope you don't mind that I provide an according solution.

You need both, the `"lm"` objects, denoted as `fit*` below, and the matrices with robust standard errors resulting from `coeftest`, denoted by `rob.fit*` below. *Example:*

```
fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
fit2 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + am, mtcars)
library(sandwich);library(lmtest)
rob.fit1 <- coeftest(fit1, vcov.=vcovHC(fit1))
rob.fit2 <- coeftest(fit2, vcov.=vcovHC(fit2))
```

Then, in `texreg` use `override.*` to provide modified standard errors, as well as the p-values.

```
library(texreg)
screenreg(list(fit1, fit2),
          override.se=list(rob.fit1[,2], rob.fit2[,2]),
          override.pvalues=list(rob.fit1[,4], rob.fit2[,4]))

# =================================
#              Model 1    Model 2  
# ---------------------------------
# (Intercept)  30.10 ***  26.58 ***
#              (2.41)     (1.47)   
# hp           -0.07 ***  -0.06 ***
#              (0.02)     (0.01)   
# am                       5.28 ***
#                         (1.22)   
# ---------------------------------
# R^2           0.60       0.78    
# Adj. R^2      0.59       0.77    
# Num. obs.    32         32                        <-- THERE THEY ARE!!
# RMSE          3.86       2.91    
# =================================
# *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Just replace `screenreg` with `texreg` for LaTeX, or `htmlreg` for HTML, whatever you want.

I'm sure this might be somehow also possible with `stargazer`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jay.sf that `stargazer` will not show test statistics if `coeftest` objects instead of regression models are supplied. But there is a solution without the need to switch to `texreg`.

You can still use `coeftest` to find robust standard errors. You need to save the standard errors from each model in one numeric vector, and then combine all vectors into a single list, which will be suppplied to the `se` option in `stargazer`. But be careful that `stargazer` must rely on the element names in those vectors to match each robust standard error to each independent variable. So, for each model, you should subset the `coeftest` object by using [,2], as the second column is for robust standard errors. The variable names will be retained in this way. Then, you can merge all numeric vectors into a list and supply it into the `se` option.

A sample code that does not fit into your dataset:

(I have eight models to run, from q4a1 to q4a8, and they are stored in the list q4a. I want to find two-way clustered standard errors instead of robust standard errors.)

```
se.q4a <- sapply(q4a, function(z) coeftest(z, vcov = vcovCL, cluster = ~ wbcode + cluster)[, 2])
stargazer(q4a[[1]], q4a[[2]], q4a[[3]], q4a[[4]], q4a[[5]], q4a[[6]], q4a[[7]], q4a[[8]], keep = c("rlaw", "corrupt"), type = "text", se = se.q4a)
```